# Database objects visulization

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am working on a hobby project. It is a tool for visualizing database objects and dependencies, similar to this one here http://bit.ly/gmqkvW. Does any one know if the tool uses SVG for the graphics. How would I go about doing similar visulization in .net?

Kindest Regards!

Comment: It sounds like your basic question is how to display certain data visually in .NET, which is far too broad to answer here: you can display data any way you like. If you can make your question more specific you may get a better response.

Comment: I mean what libraries/framework are out there that I can use to get a similar UI.